# Rules for validating CSS height/width?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, servercontrols

I'm creating an ASP.NET control that outputs `<object>` and `<embed>` tags. I want the control to have "Height" and "Width" properties, since both of those tags require them. I was also thinking of validating the height and width at runtime. I'm wondering exactly what the valid ranges are so I can be sure I have valid sizes.

These are the types of height and width settings I've seen before. Are these all valid? Where could I find all the accepted formats? Are there any values that are considered invalid, but are used as tricks for cross-browser compatibility?

- 1px
- 10%
- 99.99%
- 100

I may just go the route of letting the user input whatever they want in these fields, but now I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the W3C page for `height`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_height.asp) under Property Values. To answer your specific question, all of those values are permitted. Omitting the `px` has no effect.